# if test not showing section of code - spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a region in my jsp that I want to display a list of the departments by testing if the list is not empty. This is the code in my addDeparment.jsp file

```
<c:if test="${!empty departments}">
    <table align="center" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Department ID</th>
            <th>Department Name</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${departments}" var="department">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${department.departmentId}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${department.departmentName}"/></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="editDepartment?departmentId=${department.departmentId}">Edit</a> | <a href="deleteDepartment?departmentId=${department.departmentId}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

this is the controller that gets all the departments and attaches them into a HashMap collection

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addDepartment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addCategory(@ModelAttribute("command")  Department department,
            BindingResult result) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("departments",  departmentService.getDepartments());
        return new ModelAndView("addDepartment");
    }
```

If I run the code, this section of the view in the jsp file does not display

```
<tr>
            <th>Department ID</th>
            <th>Department Name</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
```

cannot figure out what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller, you need to pass your model to the `ModelAndView` object as follows:

```
return new ModelAndView("addDepartment", model);
```

References:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-